# How to remove brackets from output (i.e. [ ]) and other

Tags: python, enumerate

I am having trouble getting the right output out for my code(for school).
  st = input string 
  ch = input character(this is for python to search for ch in st) 
  The code find the both uppercase and the lowercase of the character that I put in for ch, and shows their position in the output(in reverse order). 
  So, I typed this code in

```
def whichPositionsRev (st, ch):
    if ch in st:
        inverseFindChar = [index for index,char in enumerate(list(st)) if char==ch ]
        return "Yes..." + str(inverseFindChar[::-1])
    else:
        return "No"
```

I am suppose to get 'Yes...8 5 2 ' as a return value(if I typed in 'abXabXabX' for st and 'X' for ch), but I'm keep getting 'Yes...[8, 5, 2]' as an output. I want to know
which part code is causing it to put in brackets and commas in the return output?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling `str()` on an array, you are getting the string representation of the array.

Replace

```
str(inverseFindChar[::-1])
```

with

```
" ".join(str(x) for x in inverseFindChar[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The part you're asking about is the `str()` function call. Python puts brackets and commas in the output for you to make it easier to see the array elements.

If you want to get the array elements separated by spaces, use

```
" ".join(map(str, inverseFindChar[::-1]))
```

Comment: Ah, ok that fixed the problem with the brackets, thank you. Do you know, by any chance, how to add space(' ') at the end of the output? I am now getting the right output, but the question is asking me to get an output as 'Yes...8 5 2 ', where I'm not getting that extra space at the end.

Comment: @recursive yes I did, but one of the test code is hidden, I tried putting in space at the end, and it said Fail for the result.